# Cryptic Jeopardy

Tags: cryptic-clues

**Puzzlers!** Welcome to ***Cryptic Jeopardy***, where your cryptic-crossword solving skills will be pushed to their limits -- in *direct competition* with your fellow puzzlers! Here's how it works:

- If you see a clue you know the answer to, post the answer in a partial answer. Make sure you post an explanation of how you got to the answer as well.
- If your answer is correct, I will award you the points associated with that clue on my scoreboard! However, if your answer is wrong, you don't get another chance to answer that question, so make sure you get it right!
- After every clue has been answered, the puzzler with the most points gets the green check!

Here are your categories and your clues:

---

### Code-Dependent

**$100**:

> Dimple between eyes due to peculiar flames

**$200**:

> Cross isoprenes off

**$300**:

> Particle goes back-to-back

**$400**:

> Ill will

**$500**:

> Angry? Upset? Read between the lines

---

### One Of Us

**$100**:

> Crafty, crooked

**$200**:

> Bless borough in disarray

**$300**:

> New Yorker said he would summon something

**$400**:

> Small dekagram atom

**$500**:

> Exciting; eating; excited; eaten

---

### O, The Places You'll Go

**$100**:

> Messy bathrooms

**$200**:

> Complain about

**$300**:

> Practice freely between rounds

**$400**:

> Blended egg drink

**$500**:

> Unit of power wrapped around and around

---

### Fly Me A River

**$100**:

> Break a writing utensil

**$200**:

> Royal weaselly carnivore

**$300**:

> Small indent in power tool

**$400**:

> Hear the ocean? Carelessly dock, then yell violently

**$500**:

> Jessica and Mr. Rick finally get together

---

### An Unreal Vacation

**$100**:

> First off the ungulate's back

**$200**:

> Titan holds muddled metal

**$300**:

> Curious last character accompanies birth

**$400**:

> In audition, belly button ring breaks

**$500**:

> Dad, it echoes me

---

**Solved Clues:**

> **Code-Dependent**
> \$100 - Pete
> \$200 - Deusovi
> \$300 - dennisdeems
> \$400 - dennisdeems
> \$500 - Pete
>
> **One of Us**
> \$100 - Deusovi
> \$200
> \$300 - Pete
> \$400
> \$500
>
> **O, the Places You'll Go**
> \$100 - Pete
> \$200 - Pete
> \$300 - Pete
> \$400 - Alconja
> \$500 - kanchirk
>
> **Fly Me A River**
> \$100 - dennisdeems
> \$200 - Pete
> \$300 - Pete
> \$400 - Pete
> \$500 - dennisdeems
>
> **An Unreal Vacation**
> \$100 - dennisdeems
> \$200 - dennisdeems
> \$300
> \$400 - Pete
> \$500 - dennisdeems

**Leaderboard:**

> $1.$ Pete (\$2800)
> $2.$ dennisdeems (\$2100)
> $3.$ kanchirk (\$500)
> $4.$ Alconja (\$400)
> $5.$ Deusovi (\$300)

---

Good luck, and have fun!

---

<sup>*Note:* The cryptic clues don't include definitions since they fit into categories. They also don't include letter count, but if they prove to be too difficult I will add them. There are some more difficult cryptic techniques being used here than in typical crosswords, specifically synonym anagrams. They're hopefully all solvable, though!</sup>

Comment: Can I answer more than one question?

Comment: @BenFrankel answer as many as you can!

Comment: This is pretty cool. So the categories are effectively the definitions? And the points per answer, that's pretty cool.  Did I mention you've had a pretty cool idea here?

Comment: None of the responses so far are in the form of questions. :(

Comment: Can you mark the ones that have been answered successfully?

Comment: Ugh, I've got a hunch for OOU 500 but I can't quite make it work.

Comment: Thought I'd come back and have another look at this one (also not sure if you noticed my attempt at Unreal Vacations for $300 a few weeks ago). Could the users for the One of Us category be anyone, or did you choose from the top, say, 100 users?

Comment: Why are the clues hidden?

Answer (score 4):

The $100 One Of Us clue is...

> me! DEVIOUS is an anagram of DEUSOVI. (That's actually the origin of the username. :D )

The $200 Code clue is...

> EXPRESSION (anagram of ISOPRENES + X)

Comment: @$100: Really? I thought you were naming yourself after some sort of Indian god or something.

Comment: And I tried so hard to find a place for your name in my own puzzle, but had no idea of a clue about it. Darn, should've thought about anagrams...

Comment: I read it as 'deus' and 'ovi'. Deus being god, and 'ovi' referring to 'egg'. Deusovi, therefor, would read as 'god of eggs'.

Comment: @Tim: Nope, never even considered that. It's interesting how different people read it, though.

Comment: Oh, what? All this time I was sure it was Deusovi ->(reverse)-> ivosueD = IV O sued = 4 Oxygen sued ->(mad lib)->  'For rocks itch ensued'. In retrospect rocks don't have a nervous system so my interpretation might have been kind of nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

Code-Dependent

$300

> particle = ion; goes back-to-back = recurs --> RECURSION

$400

> anagram (ill) of "testament" (will) : STATEMENT

O, The Places You'll Go

$400

> <s>OSAKA - 'blend' of O ('egg') and SAKE (drink)</s>

Fly Me A River

$100

> Break a writing utensil : anagram for "a pencil" : PELICAN

$500

> Jessica and Mr. Rick finally get together : charade : alba + ross + t (last letter in "get" = ALBATROSS

An Unreal Vacation

$100

> 'ot' (first letters of 'off' and 'the') placed after 'camel' ( ungulate's back) : CAMELOT

$200

> Atlas (titan) contains (holds) anagram of 'tin' (muddled metal) : ATLANTIS

$500

> Pa (Dad) + it x2 ("echoes") + I (me) : PAITITI

Answer (score 4):

*O, The Places You'll Go*

**$400** - Blended egg drink

> **Oregon** - eggnog (egg drink) => roe nog (roe is fish eggs) => oregon (blended = anagram)

---

*An Unreal Vacation*

**$300** - Curious last character accompanies birth

> **[Norombega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norumbega)** - The last letter of the Greek alphabet (curious last character) is "Omega", into which we mix (accompany) the letters from "born" (birth).

Comment: brilliant! `````

Answer (score 3):

Code-Dependent

$100

> IDENTIFIER - DENT (dimple) between two I's (eyes), anagram of FIRE (peculiar flames)

$500

> LITERAL - Anagram of IRATE (Angry? Upset?) between two L's (between the lines)

One Of Us

$300

> ALCONJA - I'll conjure (summon something) with a New York accent

O, The Places You'll Go

$100

> OSLO - Anagram of (messy) LOOS (bathrooms)

$200

> OMAN - Anagram of (about) MOAN (complain)

$300

> ONTARIO - Anagram of (freely) TRAIN (practice) between O and O (rounds)

Fly Me A River

$200

> KINGFISHER - KING (royal) FISHER (weaselly carnivore)

$300

> SANDPIPER - dice PIP (small indent) inside (in) SANDER (power tool)

$400

> CORMORANT - C sounds like sea (hear the ocean?), anagram of (carelessly) MOOR (dock),  RANT (yell violently)

An Unreal Vacation

$400

> AVALON - Anagram of (breaks) NAVAL sounds like navel (In audition, belly button) and O (ring)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late in on the action, but thought I'd try to solve some of the remaining clues.

One of Us

$200

> **xnor** - anagram (in disarray) of "ronx" (B-less [Bronx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bronx), a borough of New York City)

$400

> **dmg** - "damg" (deka-milligram, a small dekagram) without the 'a' (a-tom, where "tom" comes from a Greek word meaning "cut")

Comment: 400 seems kinda tenuous to me, but 200 definitely looks right! Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

O, The Places You'll Go

$500

Unit of power wrapped around and around

> Ottawa => O-Watt-a -> @ -> at

---

Since I am unsure. Hint for others.

$400

Blended egg drink

> Some place possibly an anagram or similar to "Omelet" or "Omlette"

Answer (score 0):

My guess for

One of us

$400:

> Small dekagram atom -> User [smallatom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/226/smallatom)

Code-Dependent

$500

> Angry? Upset? Read between the lines can't help but thing -> Extracting "Rage" from (Angry Upset) -> It must be HULK.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: 
One of us  -  $500

> Who is Wa Kai? My profile picture fits it really god :)
>  COOKIES?!?!